# Meteor.js reactive html5 geolocation position.coords

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, geolocation

I'm a meteor.js nuub, but I did spend quite a bit of time trying to figure this one out.

I'm trying to reactively update my UI based on the HTML5 geolocation API callback passed into getCurrentPosition.  However, the UI is not updating with my current code.

Can you offer suggestions and/or a solution?  Here are the details:

Basics: meteor server is running, serving other data to/from mongo via collections successfully

I have a main page (main.html):

```
<head>
  <title>Geolocation</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <header class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <a class="brand" href="/">Geolocation</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="locationDemo">
    {{> location}}
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

that references a template (location.js):

```
<template name="location">
  <div>
    Lat: {{lat}}
  </div>
  <div>
    Lon: {{lon}}
  </div>
</template>
```

that has this associated helper (location.js):

```
_lat = {
  current: 0,
  dep: new Deps.Dependency,
  get: function(){
    this.dep.depend();

    if(this.current === 0){
      getLocation();
    }

    return this.current;
  },
  set: function(value){
    this.current = value;
    this.dep.changed();
    Deps.flush();
    return this.current;
  }
};

_lon = {
  current: 0,
  dep: new Deps.Dependency,
  get: function(){
    this.dep.depend();

    if(this.current === 0){
      getLocation();
    }

    return this.current;
  },
  set: function(value){
    this.current = value;
    this.dep.changed();
    Deps.flush();
    return this.current;
  }
};

function getLocation(){
  if (navigator.geolocation)
  {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
  }
  else{
    console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}

function showPosition(position)
{
  _lat.set(position.coords.latitude);
  _lon.set(position.coords.longitude);
}

function showError(error) {
  switch(error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      console.log("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      console.log("Location information is unavailable.");
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      console.log("The request to get user location timed out.");
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      console.log("An unknown error occurred.");
      break;
  }
}

Template.location.helpers({
  lat: _lat.get(),
  lon: _lon.get()
});
```

Comment: are you expecting it to update when `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` changes? If so, you'll probably need a `Deps.autorun`, but even then I'm not sure that geolocation can be used as a reactive data source.

Comment: Hey Cristian,  yeah, I thought that _lat and _lon could be used as the reactive vars.  I was thinking Deps.autorun but I'm not sure where to call it.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know `navigator.geolocation` is not a reactive data source. So this won't work without some explicit polling. Another thing that you've got wrong is that your helpers are not functions, so they couldn't be called repeatedly.

This might work (not tested):

```
Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        Session.set('lat', position.coords.latitude);
        Session.set('lon', position.coords.longitude);
    });
}, 5000);

Template.location.helpers({
  lat: function() { return Session.get('lat'); },
  lon: function() { return Session.get('lon'); }
});
```

Comment: Thanks again Christian.  I was asking for the location only once (the 'if' statement in the getter), but I do like the polling idea.  However, I was looking to make _lat.get() the reactive source, not the geolocation API.  Geolocation is working, just not the Deps stuff.

Comment: Take 2: Christian, you were totally right!  What I was missing is the binding of the Template to the _lat & _lon objects - which was also pointed out by Slava Kim (meteor google group). It's totally working now.

Answer (score 1):

To get geolocation to work in Meteor apps compiled as native iOS apps, I needed to add the geolocation package available at https://atmospherejs.com/mdg/geolocation