# Subscription reactive on Session changes causes #each to redraw every entity

Tags: session, meteor, reactive-programming

So here's the catch: I store the user's coordinates using [this neat solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24842710/1439597). Here is my implementation:

```
updateLoc = function () {
    var position = Geolocation.latLng() || {lat:0,lng:0};
    Session.set('lat', position.lat);
    Session.set('lon', position.lng);
};

Meteor.startup(function() {
    updateLoc(); // set at 0, 0 to begin with
    Meteor.setTimeout(updateLoc, 1000); // get first coordinates 1 second in
    Meteor.setInterval(updateLoc, 5000); // then, every 5 seconds
});
```

I have an `entitiesList` route waiting on entities to be subscribed, according to those two session variables:

```
this.route('entitiesList', {
    path: '/',
    waitOn: function() {
        if (Meteor.userId())
            return Meteor.subscribe('entities', {lat: Session.get('lat'),lon: Session.get('lon')});
    },
    data: function() {
        return {entities: Entities.find()};
    }
});
```

Here is the publication:

```
Meteor.publish('entities', function (position) {
    if (position.lon !== null && position.lat !== null) {
        return Entities.find({location: {
            $near: {$geometry:{type: "Point", coordinates: [position.lon, position.lat]},$maxDistance:500}}
        }});
    }
    this.ready();
});
```

Finally, the entitiesList template :

```
<template name="entitiesList">
  <div class="entities">
    <h1>Entities list</h1>
    {{#each entities}}
      {{> entityItem}}
    {{else}}
        <p>No entity found. Looking up...</p>
        {{>spinner}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Now! This solution works. Entities are listed correctly, updated every 5 seconds according to the user's location.

The only issue lies in rendering: when the reactivity is due to an update of Session variables, the entire set of entities is deleted and redrawn. But when a change occurs in the Entity Collection (say, an entity gets deleted / created) only this change is re-rendered accordingly in the template.

What this produces is a list that flashes very annoyingly every 5 seconds. I thought of removing the `#each` block and sort of write it myself using `this.autorun()` in the `rendered` function of the template, and to redraw the list in a more optimized fashion using jQuery, but it would be an obnoxious hack, with HTML chunks of code outside of the template files... Surely there's gotta be another way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you change your session variables, your subscription is loading and Iron Router sets his **loading** template and that's why it's flickering.

Instead of using iron-router you could do:

```
Template.entitiesList.created=function()
{
    var self=this
    this.isLoading=new ReactiveVar(false)
    this.isFirstLoading=new ReactiveVar(true)
    this.autorun(function(){

        self.isLoading.set(true)
        Meteor.subscribe('entities', {lat: Session.get('lat'),lon: Session.get('lon')},function(err){
            self.isLoading.set(false)
            self.isFirstLoading.set(false)
        });
    })
}
Template.entitiesList.helpers({
    entities:function(){return Entities.find()}
    isLoading:function(){Template.instance().isLoading.get()
    isFirstLoading:function(){Template.instance().isFirstLoading.get()
})


<template name="entitiesList">
  <div class="entities">
    <h1>Entities list</h1>
    {{#if isFirstLoading}}
       <p>Looking up...<p/>
       {{>spinner}}
    {{else}}
        {{#each entities}}
            {{> entityItem}}
        {{else}}
            <p>No entity found</p>
        {{/each}}
        {{#if isLoading}}
            {{>spinner}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Many thanks! Exactly what I was looking for: a clean hack :) I just added an `else` statement to the `each` block to display a notification when no entity is found in the area.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddling through with iron-router, I found that there actually is an option to not render the loading template on every new subscription triggered: [the subscriptions option](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#the-subscriptions-option). Just had to replace `waitOn` by `subscriptions` and I get the desired result.